# Using System.Diagnostics.Conditional to exclude methods from a library

Tags: c#

I'm making two versions of a library; one for delivery to a customer, and one for in-house use.

The difference between the two versions is that the in-house version will contain methods that the customer must not have.

Up to now, I've used old-style #ifdef'ing to differentiate the code, but I'd like to transition to System.Diagnostics.Conditional.

If I use System.Diagnostics.Conditional to exclude a method, is there some way a user could discover the method, reverse-engineer it, or execute it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method will still be present, but the [calls are removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Applying ConditionalAttribute to a method indicates to compilers that a ***call to the method* should not be compiled** into Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL)

So upon decompilation your client can discover the method body, and when they reference the assembly containing the method, they can simply call it from their code.